# Multilanguage site, attaching lang files - google positioning

Tags: php, html, positioning, multilingual

Hello I asking about positioning in google inside HTML tags.
I use this script below and everything works well but how with HTML title tag. should I make title tag like? if not it will be problematic.

```
<title>$_LANG['title']</title>
```

or

```
<title>Servers ots list</title>
```

How it would looks like whereas the positioning.

Is good my way to the multilanguage site for positioning?

```html
if(preg_match("(localhost)", SERVER_ADDRESS)){
    $lang="en";
    $_SESSION['lang']=$lang;
    include ('lang/'.$lang.'.php');
}else{
      if(SERVER_ADDRESS == "http://tibiaservers.net/"){
            $default_lang="en";
            curlLang("en");
      }elseif (SERVER_ADDRESS == "http://germany.tibiaservers.net/") {
            $default_lang="de";
            curlLang("de");
      }elseif(SERVER_ADDRESS == "http://sweden.tibiaservers.net/"){
             $default_lang="sv";
            curlLang("sv");
      }elseif(SERVER_ADDRESS == "http://brazil.tibiaservers.net/"){
             $default_lang="pt";
            curlLang("pt");
      }else{
            $default_lang="pl";
            curlLang("pl");
     }
}      

// ATTACHING FILE

if ( isset ( $_POST['lang'] ) ){
  $lang = addslashes ( $_POST['lang'] );
  if ( is_file ( 'lang/' .$lang. '.php' ) )
{ $_SESSION['lang']=$lang; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `<title><?php echo $_LANG['title']; ?></title>`

I recommend you to use arrays, switch etc.

I use this: [-click-](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/download/zip/package/5075/name/addmultiplelanguajes-2009-08-15.zip) (multilanguage support, by @$_POST or detect it. No need to create something like es.site.com)

Check the index.php file in the zip!

Hope it helps